# Can I update all fields from an Object in Salescloud from Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder, sales-cloud, data-synchronization

I'm trying to update several fields that I can see in the synchronized object within data sources but when I create an update lead activity in Journey Builder, these fields are not available to update.

Can all the fields be updated? If no, why?

The fields that require updates are:

1. CreatedDate
2. EmailBouncedDate
3. et4ae5__HasOptedOutOfMobile__c

Comment: CreatedDate would be a system date, so you wouldn't be able to update that

Comment: It might also be a case that those fields are read-only or the MC API user doesn't have access to those fields in Sales Cloud.